# What does (gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w) represent?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want actual world space distance, and I get the feeling from experimentation that

`(gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w)`

is the depth in world space? But I'm not too sure.

**EDIT** I've just [found where I had originally located this snippet of code](http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/glsl_fog/p04.php). Apparently it is the actual depth from the camera?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is exactly. Are you asking what gl_FragCoord.z's value is? Or what gl_FragDepth's value should be? Or simply how to get a world-space depth? The latter requires explaining what exactly you mean by world-space depth, since "depth" is usually defined as the planar distance to the camera.

Comment: As stated in the question, I want the actual distance, in world space units, from the camera (or it's near plane, if that is more appropriate).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This was asked (by the same person) and [answered elsewhere](https://community.khronos.org/t/gl-fragcoord-z-gl-fragcoord-w-for-quick-depth-calculation-camera-to-fragment/68919/4). I'm paraphrasing and embellishing the answer here:

As stated in section 15.2.2 of the [OpenGL 4.3 core profile specification (PDF)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec43.core.pdf), `gl_FragCoord.w` is `1 / clip.w`, where `clip.w` is the W component of the clip-space position (ie: what you wrote to `gl_Position`).

`gl_FragCoord.z` is generated by the following process, assuming the usual transforms:

1. Camera-space to clip-space transform, via projection matrix multiplication in the vertex shader. `clip.z = (projectionMatrix * cameraPosition).z`
2. Transform to normalized device coordinates. `ndc.z = clip.z / clip.w`
3. Transform to window coordinates, using the [`glDepthRange` near/far values](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glDepthRange). `win.z = ((dfar-dnear)/2) * ndc.z + (dfar+dnear)/2`.

Now, using the default depth range of near=0, far=1, we can define `win.z` in terms of clip-space: `(clip.z/clip.w)/2 + 0.5`. If we then divide this by `gl_FragCoord.w`, that is the equivalent of multiplying by `clip.w`, thus giving us:

```
(gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w) = clip.z/2 + clip.w/2 = (clip.z + clip.w) / 2
```

Using the standard projection matrix, `clip.z` represents a scale and offset from camera-space Z component. The scale and offset are defined by the camera's near/far depth values. `clip.w` is, again in the standard projection matrix, just the negation of the camera-space Z. Therefore, we can redefine our equation in those terms:

```
(gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w) = (A * cam.z + B -cam.z)/2 = (C * cam.z + D)
```

Where `A` and `B` represent the offset and scale based on near/far, and `C = (A - 1)/2` and `D = B / 2`.

Therefore, `gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w` is *not* the camera-space (or world-space) distance to the camera. Nor is it the camera-space planar distance to the camera. But it *is* a linear transform of the camera-space depth. You could use it as a way to compare two depth values together, if they came from the same projection matrix and so forth.

To actually compute the camera-space Z, you need to either pass the camera near/far from your matrix (OpenGL [already gives you the range near/far](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Built-in_Variable_(GLSL)#Shader_uniforms)) and compute those `A` and `B` values from them, or you need to use the inverse of the projection matrix. Alternatively, you could just use the projection matrix directly yourself, since fragment shaders can use the same uniforms available to vertex shaders. You can pick the `A` and `B` terms directly from that matrix. `A = projectionMatrix[2][2]`, and `B = projectionMatrix[3][2]`.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_FragDepth.xml):

```
Available only in the fragment language, gl_FragDepth is an output variable that
is used to establish the depth value for the current fragment. If depth buffering
is enabled and no shader writes to gl_FragDepth, then the fixed function value
for depth will be used (this value is contained in the z component of
gl_FragCoord) otherwise, the value written to gl_FragDepth is used.
```

So, it looks like `gl_FragDepth` should just be `gl_FragCoord.z` unless you've set it somewhere else in your shaders.

Comment: Nope, it isn't. That's what I originally thought. I just swapped out the `gl_FragCoord.z` in my equation with `gl_FragDepth` (for the production of linear fog) to check your answer, and suddenly my entire scene is black irrespective of distance. Whereas when I leave in the original `gl_FragCoord.z`, I see fog after some specified distance.

Comment: @NickWiggill: You cannot argue with the OpenGL specification. If your code is producing that result, then it is either due to a bug in your code or a bug in the implementation. That's what is written in the spec, and therefore that is how OpenGL behaves.

Comment: @NicolBolas. Interesting you should say that; look at the edit I just made to the question. I will also state again that according to the scale of my objects in the world, I am pretty willing to agree with what the article presents there. It would be nice, though, to know whether this is the most efficient way to get world depth. From what I see [here](http://olivers.posterous.com/linear-depth-in-glsl-for-real), it is much more efficient than deriving it from gl_FragDepth.

Comment: @NickWiggill: Just because some idiot on the internet says it doesn't make it true. The OpenGL specification defines what `gl_FragCoord` represents, not a tutorial. And the spec is very clear: `gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w` is errant nonsense.

Comment: @NicolBolas Temper, temper! I see that you don't understand the maths behind it, then. If you did, you would have disproven it thus. Oh well!

Comment: @NickWiggill: [I don't understand the maths behind it?](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut05%20Overlap%20and%20Depth%20Buffering.html) [I *don't understand the maths behind it?*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_eye_space_from_window_space) I don't need to go around disproving nonsense; the spec says what it says, and that page is wrong.

Comment: @NickWiggill: Yes, people promoting non-information as real and downvoting real facts winds me up.

Comment: @Engineer You are mixing INPUT variables with OUTPUT values. 'gl_FragCoord.z' is available to you as INPUT. This is not true for 'gl_FragDepth'. It is an OUTPUT value that shall be filled by you. If you don't fill it, specs say that it will be filled automatically with 'gl_FragCoord.z'. You should not use 'gl_FragDepth' as INPUT.

Answer (score 1):

As

```
gl_FragCoord.w = 1.0 / gl_Position.w
```

And (likely) your projection matrix gets w from -z (if the last column is 0,0,-1,0) then;

```
float distanceToCamera = 1.0 / gl_FragCoord.w;
```