# Why is the value of `gl_FragCoord.z` is always 0.5?

Tags: graphics, glsl, webgl

I am working on a complicated WebGL program where I have to recover depth in fragment shader.

However, the value of `gl_FragCoord.z` is always 0.5, quite strange.

```c
// I use this method to verify the value of gl_FragCoord.z
if (gl_FragCoord.z == 0.5) {
    fragColor= vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
} 
else {
    fragColor= vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5);
}
```

The depth test is turned on with

```
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.depthFunc(gl.ALWAYS);
```

I have seen many similar problems with `gl_FragCoord.z` valued zero, which is always caused by disable depth test. So I wonder what might cause my problem? Or is there any other way to recover depth of fragment without `gl_FragCoord.z`?

Thanks!

---

I have launched a [issue](https://github.com/huggingface/gsplat.js/issues/89) of the original project I was working on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does (gl\_FragCoord.z / gl\_FragCoord.w) represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711252/what-does-gl-fragcoord-z-gl-fragcoord-w-represent)

Comment: @vallentin no, in my case the value of `gl_FragCoord.w` is always 1.

Comment: You said `0.5` in the title, and now you're saying `1`. Are you using an orthographic matrix?

Comment: the value of `gl_FragCoord.z` is 0.5 and `gl_FragCoord.w` is 1, I am using perspective projection